# Convert Nested json to dotted Map in groovy

Tags: groovy

How to convert a nested json to dotted map in groovy?

```
import groovy.json.*

def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText('{"person"{"name":"Guillaume","age":33,"pets":["dog","cat"]}}')

println(json)
```

output:

```
[person:[name:Guillaume, age:33, pets:[dog, cat]]]
```

But i am looking for following output

```
[person.name:Guillaume, person.age:33, person.pets:[dog, cat]]]
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: `person.name:Guillaume, person.age:33, etc`?

Comment: Can I ask why? This seems an odd requirement... Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: @tim_yates, that's right. Let me update my post.

Comment: http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td364360

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this with collectMany:

```
def result = json.collectMany{ 
    k, v -> v.collect {  
        l -> if(l.key != null && l.value != null  ) {
            json.find().key+"."+l.key+":"+l.value
        }
    }
}
println(result)​
```

This is output is:

```
[person.name:Guillaume, person.age:33, person.pets:[dog, cat]]
```

Good Luck!